# Oracle SQL: How to give user the permissions to SELECT from a table?

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-sql-developer

I'm not very familiar with Oracle SQL at all, but using our admin account I ran the following query on our Oracle database server: GRANT SELECT ON Table1 TO OtherUser. I then committed this change (not sure if you need to even commit this?)

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to our Oracle database and after I ran the above GRANT statement from our admin account, I would've thought I would see Table1 listed under the Table objects node when I connect as OtherUser, but I do not see it and cannot select from it when I try.

Is there any other permissions I need to grant, or anything else I need to do that I missed?

Edit: When I query DBA_TAB_PRIVS I do see Table1 listed with the SELECT privilege for grantee OtherUser, even though from OtherUser's perspective I can't see Table1 under the Tables node in Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects owned by other users are not listed under your objects in SQL Developer.

Expand **Other Users**, **Owner** (username), **Tables**, and you will find the table there.

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, but shouldn't I be able to SELECT from the table in a worksheet for the OtherUser account (the one that doesn't own the object but does have SELECT privilege granted to it)?

Comment: @J.D. - You can, with specifying the owner of the table: `select * from owner.table_name;`.

Comment: That's actually how I'm trying to SELECT and it's still not working. I'm getting the error:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 12


The query I'm running from a worksheet for OtherUser is:
SELECT *
FROM AdminAccount.Table1;
-- AdminAccount is the owner of Table1

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I am able to drag the table into the Query Builder and then run the statement from the Query Builder. And when I look at the SQL (Ctrl+Q), it shows the exact same query I'm trying to run from the Worksheet, even though in the Worksheet it gives me an error.

Comment: Never mind, now it is working from the Worksheet tab. Bug with Oracle SQL Developer perhaps? In any case, I appreciate your help.